# jquery lightbox on thumbnail click change main image

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I am using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js for lightbox and in that lightbox i want to use some jquery. Basically, It is a product lightbox on the the left there is a main image and on the right there are 3-4 thumbnails.

I want when user clicks the thumbnails main image should get changed according to thumb.

```
<div class="product-lightBox">
            <img src="images/lb-brand-logo.jpg">
            <div class="product">

                <div class="left">
                    <img src="images/lb-product-img.jpg">
                    <img src="images/lb-product-img.jpg">
                     <img src="images/lb-product-img.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Product<span>2088</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Color</h5>
                        <ul class="color">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/lb-thumb-img1.jpg"><span>Black<img src="images/color-pointer.png"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/lb-thumb-img2.jpg"><span>Red<img src="images/color-pointer.png"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/lb-thumb-img3.jpg"><span>Brown<img src="images/color-pointer.png"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Size<span>5 - 11</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Prize<span class="price">INR 999</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="des">
                        <h4>Description</h4>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="detail">
                            <p>This is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <img src="images/lb-social-icons.jpg">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: so what was the question?

Comment: I want to write a script for in lightbox for my html code. As mentioned above there is a big thumbnail which is a main image and that image in call in this (<div class="left"></div>) and In that html code there are three thumbnails when any of the thumbnail is clicked that main image should get changed and an active class should get added in (li) of that thumbnail.

Comment: `I want to write a script` ... that's good. Then do it, and show your code and ask for help for the part that doesn't work (stackoverflow isn't a cookbook or a club of code monkeys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little modification to your HTML:

Add a data attribute to the thumbnails

```
<img src="images/lb-thumb-img1.jpg" data-image="images/lb-big-img1.jpg">
```

Then do something like this:

```
$(".color img").click(function()
{
    var image = $(this).data("image");
    $(".left img").attr("src", image);
});
```